# Tabular vs pmatrix

Tags: tables

In a recent post I was adviced to use `pmatrix` for typing matrices instead of tabular and I am convinced that this is really the right way. The problem is that my book concerns matrix theory and linear algebra and there are hundrends of tabular environments that have to be changed by hand, one by one. Therefore my question is this: it is worth of doing this? I mean, this is something that will improve the apperance of the book and suppress undesired errors and warnings? The result of using these two approaches (`pmatrix` and `tabular`) it seems the same (at least to me). Thanks a lot!!! Athanasios.

Comment: using `tabular` is wrong and it would be worth changing even if the output were the same but you will get better spacing for the brackets from `\begin{pmatrix}...` than from `\left(\begin{tablular}...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyway, you shouldn't use `tabular`, but `array` in math mode.

The generic environment is more versatile as you can set alignments per column, whereas in all the  `xmatrix` environments, columns are centred. On the other hand, the code for `pmatrix` is lighter.

In addition, `mathtools` defines `xmatrix*` environments, which can take an optional argument : `[l]`, `[c]` (the default) or `[r]`, with the obvious meaning, which ensure  *all* column are aligned accordingly. This adds some touch of versatility.